# Algolia docsearch commercial version

Tags: algolia

Is there a commercial version of Algolia docsearch that does not display the Algolia logo at the bottom of the results list?

I mean, if I create a commercial account, and still use docsearch, I suppose the logo is still displayed. I wonder if there is an easy way to get rid of that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the docsearch crawler](https://github.com/algolia/docsearch-scraper) which is open source to crawl your website on your own Algolia account. Then you can use [docsearch.js](https://github.com/algolia/docsearch) which is also open source to display the results.

As soon as you have a [paying plan it's ok to remove the logo](https://www.algolia.com/pricing).